# Cellular data usage irreproducible

Tags: iphone, cellular-data

I have a iPhone 6 (iOS 8.4). My problem is not that the data usage shown in settings/cellular is extremely high but rather that the sum of the usages of the apps and system services shown below is not equal to the total usage at all. There are differences with more than 200%. Do you understand what my problem is? Please do not tell me that's normal and this is background usage. Those background usages would also have to be shown up in the cellular settings.

Regards,
Nils

Comment: Could you edit in some data. What happens if you reset the statistics and run a test for 1 hour? Do the numbers add up then? I've needed a spreadsheet and several days on occasion to suss out what's using data n the past. It's not clear what you are seeing from the details thus provided.

Comment: The problem has now been solved updating to iOS 8.4.1. If it occurs again I'll do so.

Comment: Cool - put that in as an answer. Updating often is the fix :-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue has now been solved updating to iOS 8.4.1. But I don't know whether this is a long-term solution and whether the issue was directly related to iOS 8.4.